# Maximum intensity projection in pyqtgraph using GLVolumeItem

Tags: python, opengl, pyqtgraph

I would like to use the maximum intensity projection (MIP) to view some 3D medical images in pyqtgraph using GLVolumeItem. I see that there are three pre-defined `GLOptions` settings. The `translucent` and `additive` mode both look like MIP. So my questions are

1. Is it the real MIP view? If not, how should I change the `GLOptions` (e.g., `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, `GL_BLEND`, etc)?
2. Is there a website that contains the GL configurations (e.g., `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, `GL_BLEND`, etc) for different display mode?

Update:

From [this website](http://schorsch.efi.fh-nuernberg.de/roettger/index.php/VolumeRendering/MaximumIntensityProjection), I set the `GLOptions` to be

```py
{'glBlendFunc': (GL_ONE, GL_ONE), 'glBlendEquation': (GL_MAX_EXT), GL_BLEND: True}
```

However, an error pops up saying that `GL_MAX_EXT` is not defined. Any ideas how I should fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL import GL
from OpenGL.GL.EXT.blend_minmax import GL_MAX_EXT

glOptions = {'glBlendFunc': (GL_ONE, GL_ONE), 'glBlendEquation': (GL_MAX_EXT, ), GL_BLEND: True}
```

This should give you the real MIP view.